# Can not get events data from google calendar

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In component App.js I try to login with google auth and firebase and get and add data to google calendar, but I have error in get Data

```
  const SyncroWidthGoogle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.gapi.load("client:auth2", () => {
      window.gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: "api",
        clientId:
          "id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        discoveryDocs: [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest",
        ],
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
      });

      window.gapi.client.load("calendar", "v3", () => {
        console.log("loaded calrendar");
      });
      async function login() {
        const googleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        const googleUser = await googleAuth.signIn();

        const token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log(googleUser, token);

        const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token);
        
        const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          token
        );
        const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
          firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithPopup(googleProvider)
            .then((res) => {
              console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error.message);
            });
        };
        signInWithGoogle();
      }
      login();
    });
  };

  const getEvents = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.gapi.client.load("calendar", "v3", async () => {
      const events = await window.gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        calendarId: "primary",
        showDeleted: false,
        maxResults: 10,
        singleEvents: true,
      });

      console.log(events);
    });
    getEvents();
  };
```

And return

```
<button onClick={(e) => SyncroWidthGoogle(e)}>SYNCRO</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => getEvents(e)}>events</button>
```

I successful login and have in the console token and response, but when I click get events I have an error  `window.gapi.client is undefined`

Comment: are you including the appropriate script tags?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, in index html

Comment: @DanielA.White <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

Comment: dont do `async` or `defer` on that.

Comment: @DanielA.White https://prnt.sc/v0xjh1  no matter async defer

Comment: which window.gapi.client is undefined. I see multiple occurrences. Are all of them failing?

Comment: @Kaustubh-KAY i call only once and first